# Total size of downloading file using MKNetworkKit

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, mknetworkkit

I'm downloading a file using MKNetworkKit with the following code in the MKNetworkEngine subclass:

```
- (MKNetworkOperation *)downloadFileFromURL:(NSString *)urlString toFile:(NSString *)filePathString
{
    MKNetworkOperation *op = [self operationWithURLString:urlString params:nil httpMethod:@"GET"];
    [op addDownloadStream:[NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePathString append:YES]];
    [self enqueueOperation:op];
    return op;
}
```

Any hints on how to show total size of downloading file or downloading rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server sends the Content-Size header, you can get the file size from

```
operation.readonlyResponse.expectedContentLength
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get this. Below is the code

```
[downLoadEngine onDownloadProgressChanged:^(double progress) {
        progressBar.progress = progress;
}];
```

progress is the float value which is returned by mknetworkkit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it just return a float value between 0 to 1. I need the actual size of the file.